# Proxy with Flutter only works on iOS Simulator and not device

Tags: ios, flutter, proxy

I've been trying to get my iOS device to show me network traffic on Charles proxy but I haven't found any solution yet.

The code presented in here is the closest thing I have found that works:

https://medium.com/hoursofoperation/use-charles-proxy-to-debug-network-requests-in-flutter-apps-2f2083275cad

However, this only shows traffic in Charles if the project is run on simulator.
I don't know why simulator works and Device doesn't.

I tried changing the ip address of the proxy from code in the above blog to the ip address of the phone, to my computer, and to the proxy server.
Nothing works and all calls just flat out fail.

I know my phone can go through Charles normally, because other web calls still happen.
So what do I need to change for Flutter to work on my device?

Comment: hey! did you solve this issue? I'm also facing the same !

Comment: Sadly not. No Flutter developer that I've come across has ever heard of proxying before. They all meet me with a puzzled expression and think debugging networking code is not a thing anyone would/should ever do.

Comment: thanks! Omg I'm baffled... I mean, Charles/Burp... testers commonly use those tools to manipulate responses and test different scenarios. I made it work for simulator, but unfortunately doesn't work on device. Android works fine, but iOS doesn't =[

Comment: You made it work for Android device and iOS simulator? If so, how did you manage that?